# How Can i add Delete button on each row pls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

can any one let me know 
how can i add the delete button on each row pls
from the below code
[Jsfiddle][1]

```js
var counter = 1;
jQuery('a.add-author').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-6"><input type="text" name="first_name' +
        counter + '"/></div><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-6"><input type="text" name="last_name' + 
        counter + '"/></div></div>');
    jQuery('div.row').append(newRow);
});
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6"><input type="text" name="first_name" /></div><div class="col-lg-6"><input type="text" name="last_name" /></div>
</div>
<a href="#" title="" class="add-author">Add Author</a>
```

Comment: The JS Fiddle link is not working (syntax error).

Comment: You are currently add your new `.row` element to the existing. You might want to add it "after" the `.row` ;)

Answer (score 2):

To "delete" an element you can use the `jQuery('element').remove()` function.

By using the `jQuery('element').on()` you can listen to events even if the element is created later on.

Please read the documentation about `.on()` carefully!

```js
var counter = 1;
jQuery('a.add-author').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-6"><input type="text" name="first_name' +
        counter + '"/></div><div class="col-lg-6"><input type="text" name="last_name' + 
        counter + '"/></div><div><a href="#" class="delete">delete</a></div></div>');
    jQuery('.add-author').before(newRow);
});

//Bound to 'body' for this sample, bind to you own wrapper element when using this!
jQuery('body').on('click', '.delete', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.row').remove();
});
```

```css
.row { position: relative; width: 500px; height: auto; margin: 5px 0; overflow: hidden; }
.row div { position: relative; float: left; width: 150px; height: auto; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6"><input type="text" name="first_name" /></div><div class="col-lg-6"><input type="text" name="last_name" /></div>
</div>
<a href="#" title="" class="add-author">Add Author</a>
```

Comment: But its spoil the layout on wont be able to use

Comment: HI,
IS that possible to use "Delete" Function Like 
<a href="#" title="" class="add-author">Add Author</a>

Comment: I changed the sample to use jQuery's `.on()` function. This way you can bind it once instead to each element on creation.